# unnecessary vertical scrollbar in ie6

Tags: css

does any could help me how to remove unnecessary scroll bar in ie6. I have already put overflow-y: hidden; but still the same output.

thanks in advance

here is my url

http://webberzsoft.com/clients/csslayouttest/template_new.php

here is my css

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}/*for demo purposes only, use a proper reset in your final layout*/

html,body { overflow: auto; height:100%; }
body {
    font-size:100%;
    background:#777;
}
#wrapper{
    min-height:99%;
    width: 1240px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
#header {
    background:#77F;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    height: 70px;
}
#content{/*just to create top padding without tampering with min-height:100% on #inner*/
    padding:10px 0;
    overflow:hidden;/*contain floats*/
}  
    #left-index {
        float:left;
        width:220px;
    }
    #right-index {
        float:right;
        width:180px;
    }
    #middle-index {
        float:left;
        width:840px;
        overflow:hidden;/*contain floats*/
    }  
    #left-home {
        float:left;
        width:300px;
    }
    #right-home {
        float:right;
        width:940px;
    }
```

here is my html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1 align="right">Fixed Header</h1>
        <h3>IE6 gets an expression</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left-index">
            <h3>Left</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer quis tempus tristique facilisi Vestibulum. Gravida 
            rhoncus orci leo neque mattis felis Sed et tincidunt tellus. Massa ac condimentum elit ridiculus 
            eget urna wisi id Suspendisse ullamcorper.</p>
            <p>Hendrerit eros ridiculus urna ipsum leo a ac sed tortor nisl. Tincidunt Morbi justo dis odio 
            sit non sapien enim a augue. Sapien odio dui est Sed nisl id id malesuada sagittis et.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer quis tempus tristique facilisi Vestibulum. Gravida 
            rhoncus orci leo neque mattis felis Sed et tincidunt tellus. Massa ac condimentum elit ridiculus 
            eget urna wisi id Suspendisse ullamcorper.</p>
            <p>Hendrerit eros ridiculus urna ipsum leo a ac sed tortor nisl. Tincidunt Morbi justo dis odio 
            sit non sapien enim a augue. Sapien odio dui est Sed nisl id id malesuada sagittis et.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer quis tempus tristique facilisi Vestibulum. Gravida 
            rhoncus orci leo neque mattis felis Sed et tincidunt tellus. Massa ac condimentum elit ridiculus 
            eget urna wisi id Suspendisse ullamcorper.</p>
            <p>Hendrerit eros ridiculus urna ipsum leo a ac sed tortor nisl. Tincidunt Morbi justo dis odio 
            sit non sapien enim a augue. Sapien odio dui est Sed nisl id id malesuada sagittis et.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer quis tempus tristique facilisi Vestibulum. Gravida 
            rhoncus orci leo neque mattis felis Sed et tincidunt tellus. Massa ac condimentum elit ridiculus 
            eget urna wisi id Suspendisse ullamcorper.</p>
            <p>Hendrerit eros ridiculus urna ipsum leo a ac sed tortor nisl. Tincidunt Morbi justo dis odio 
            sit non sapien enim a augue. Sapien odio dui est Sed nisl id id malesuada sagittis et.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer quis tempus tristique facilisi Vestibulum. Gravida 
            rhoncus orci leo neque mattis felis Sed et tincidunt tellus. Massa ac condimentum elit ridiculus 
            eget urna wisi id Suspendisse ullamcorper.</p>
            <p>Hendrerit eros ridiculus urna ipsum leo a ac sed tortor nisl. Tincidunt Morbi justo dis odio 
            sit non sapien enim a augue. Sapien odio dui est Sed nisl id id malesuada sagittis et.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer quis tempus tristique facilisi Vestibulum. Gravida 
            rhoncus orci leo neque mattis felis Sed et tincidunt tellus. Massa ac condimentum elit ridiculus 
            eget urna wisi id Suspendisse ullamcorper.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="middle-index">
            <h3>Middle</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum sed pede non adipiscing nulla lacinia ipsum quis ac Integer. Ut consectetuer Cras fringilla 
            Ut non gravida morbi Maecenas semper vel. Vestibulum quis In Nulla Vivamus Sed feugiat Quisque et 
            ipsum tincidunt. Semper vitae cursus metus risus enim gravida tellus id dignissim nec. Justo laoreet 
            dui commodo Integer malesuada vel quis vel consequat metus. Nec id dolor Aliquam Nullam gravida 
            libero montes nunc ante Nulla. Tortor id.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum sed pede non adipiscing nulla lacinia ipsum quis ac Integer. Ut consectetuer Cras fringilla 
            Ut non gravida morbi Maecenas semper vel. Vestibulum quis In Nulla Vivamus Sed feugiat Quisque et 
            ipsum tincidunt. Semper vitae cursus metus risus enim gravida tellus id dignissim nec. Justo laoreet 
            dui commodo Integer malesuada vel quis vel consequat metus. Nec id dolor Aliquam Nullam gravida 
            libero montes nunc ante Nulla. Tortor id.</p>             
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>  
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>  
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>  
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>  
            <p class="lgmarg">testing text for scrolling</p>        
        </div>      
        <div id="right-index">
            <h3>Right</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer quis tempus tristique facilisi Vestibulum. Gravida 
            rhoncus orci leo neque mattis felis Sed et tincidunt tellus. Massa ac condimentum elit ridiculus 
            eget urna wisi id Suspendisse ullamcorper.</p>
            <p>Hendrerit eros ridiculus urna ipsum leo a ac sed tortor nisl. Tincidunt Morbi justo dis odio 
            sit non sapien enim a augue. Sapien odio dui est Sed nisl id id malesuada sagittis et.</p>            
        </div>                     
    </div><!--end content-->
</div>
```

Comment: What unnecessary scrollbar? The only scrollbar I see seems pretty necessary...

Comment: overflow-y is not supported in IE6. And yeah - I see no unnecessary scrollbar too.

Comment: vertical scroll bar to the right was became double once you resized the browser smaller using ie6

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the overflow at the html element only?

```
html { overflow:auto }
html, body { height:100% }
```